# how to disable the update button on wordpress UI completely

Tags: wordpress

I want to disable the update button on the UI completely on wordpress.

I tried disable auto updated using wp-config.php file. however I want to disable the update the button completely.

How we can do this using php file update. I dont want to use any plugin to achieve this.